# how to return data from ajax call to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm making an app which calls an JS function in php like

```
$data = "<script>JSFunction();</script>";
```

and JSFunction looks like this

```
function JSFunction(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'url/to/file',
    data:{'text':"some text here"},
    success:function(response){
        res = JSON.parse(response);
        document.write(res.data);

    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
}
```

and `$data` variable in php gets the expected results. But when I `echo $data;` then data is printed on screen but browser page continues to reload. (It don't reload actually, but that circle in browser tab continuously appears rotating). So how would I stop that reloading? or is there any other way to return data from ajax call except `document.write()`?

Comment: Your data is to call the function that asked for that data? This would be an endless loop. (yes I just stated the obvious lol)

Comment: Do not use document.write, use DOM methods to add content to the page.

Comment: $data in php calls JS function which would get some data and assign it to it. I think the problem is with `document.write()` I want something like return statement. but return doesn't work either.

Comment: @epascarello i do not want to add contents to page, i want to store these results in DB.

Comment: Than why are you using JavaScript to make a call with PHP. PHP and JavaScript do not run together. Why is the PHP code not just calling whatever?

Comment: i want to get results from JS function in PHP variable. To do further calculations with data and store in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get JSON result from PHP script you may call ajax withe proper **dataType**:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url/to/script",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url/to/php/script",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {data: data},
                    success: function (data) {
                        // do something...
                    }
            })
        }
    })
```

Don't forget to encode $data in the PHP script using **json_encode** leading with the proper header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i'm actually making a call to python script. which returns me data. Ofcourse i encode it in JSON before returning from python.

Comment: @Asadullah so adding the dataType in your JQuery ajax call will do the trick. Why you document.write data? you better use DOM functions to arrange your data on the page.

Comment: i don't want to update page contents, i want to get these results in PHP variable.

Comment: so make another ajax call inside the success callback of the first call and send the result to PHP for further processing.

Comment: @Asadullah if you want to pass data from python to php, you may make a curl call from your php script to python. see http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Oh, really forgot about curl. Looks like this would do the trick. Let me try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is considered bad practice since it can overwrite your page.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create an empty DIV with an id.
2. Use `innerHTML` to write the response to the DIV considering that your output is from trusted sources since `innerHTML` can output HTML and not only text .

**Your PHP:**

```
<div id ="x"></div>

<?php $data = "<script type='text/javascript'>JSFunction();</script>";
echo $data;
?>
```

**Your JS:**

```
function JSFunction(){
   reValue = document.getElementById("x");

   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url:'url/to/file',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{'text':"some text here"},
    success:function(response){
    x.innerHTML = response.data;

   },
    error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
   }
});
}
```

Comment: I dont want to update page contents, I want to get that returned data in PHP variable. That's why i'm calling it from PHP.